# Delete record with validate user session

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have table `tr_mobo` and I want to delete record with validate user sesson, I want some users can not delete other user data. I have data user sesson on column `user_modify_mobo`.

This my table structure
[image: table]

My Controller

```
public function delete($id) 
{
    $row = $this->M_trmobo->get_by_id($id);

    if ($row) {
        $this->M_trmobo->delete($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Delete Record Success');
        redirect(site_url('trmobo'));
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
        redirect(site_url('trmobo'));
    }
}
```

My model

```
    function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
    return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
}

function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?? show us the error.

Comment: I think you need to add a field like `**is_super_user** with default value as **N**(for no)`. Before each delete function you need to check if the value is N or not.

Comment: Mr. Prabhu, code bellow working fine not error, but all user can delete data.

Mr. Eugine Joseph, I think can't use value N, because I have many user to edit this table, and I make colum `user_modify_mobo` its save automatic insert user sesson. `sorry for my bad english`

Comment: dont delete entire record, set **is_deleted** true. Bes Practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter column name of your database table in where condition

```
function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id); //use column-name according to your database table
    return $this->db->get('table-name')->row_array();
}

function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id); //use column-name according to your database table
    $this->db->delete('table-name');
}
```